# Ajax Chart using SQL Server Data

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, charts, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying to plot chat on the aspx page. I have plotted the chart with ajaxtool kit with fixed values. Now i want to plot the chart on the basis of dat present in the SQL server. How do I bind data with the chart?

```
<ajaxToolkit:LineChart ID="LineChart1" runat="server" 
    ChartWidth="450" ChartHeight="300" ChartType="Basic" 
    ChartTitle="x,y vs year" 
    CategoriesAxis="2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012" 
    ChartTitleColor="#0E426C" CategoryAxisLineColor="#D08AD9" 
    ValueAxisLineColor="#D08AD9" BaseLineColor="#A156AB">
    <Series>
        <ajaxToolkit:LineChartSeries Name="x" 
        LineColor="#6C1E83" Data="110, 189, 255, 95, 107, 140" />
        <ajaxToolkit:LineChartSeries Name="y"  
        LineColor="#D08AD9" Data="49, 77, 95, 68, 70, 79" />
    </Series>
    </ajaxToolkit:LineChart>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in your codebehind (more control) or like that:

```
<asp:Chart ID="MyChart" runat="server" DataSourceID="MySQLDataSource">
    <Series>
        <asp:Series Name="Series1" XValueMember="x" YValueMembers="y">
        </asp:Series>
    </Series>
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
        </asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="MsSQLDataSource" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT x, y FROM [MyTable]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Oh, I missed that. It seems like the ajaxToolkit doesn't support these features (DataSource)

Comment: I already did it with asp control. and one more thing i have trying to plot it vs the time on which the value of inserted into database, but not getting the result.